# Java and RTP - related experiences

Tags: java, rtp

I'm trying to collect some experiences about using a Java library to stream RTP.
In your experience, which is the most suitable library for this task?
I am currently evaluating: JMF, FMJ, jrtp, others? (that you might suggest)

Thank you,
  Michele

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler).

Comment: Agree, I've had good results with Xuggler, and it's actually being actively maintained, unlike a lot of libraries out there.

Answer (score 0):

From recent experience, JMF is horrifically out of date and it is not maintained. For our project, we ended up switching to a C library called [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/).

Comment: I agree with JMF being horrifically out of date